# Java Regex Subexpressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern to match a specific string and return `true` if the string matches the pattern and `false` if it doesn't. Here are the conditions:

1. Must start with `[` and end with `]`
2. Each item inside the brackets have to be separated by commas
3. Each item separated by commas have to follow this regex pattern:
   `^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$`

How can I make one regex that checks for all these conditions?

Comment: No whitespace allowed anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `\w` without the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag actually matches the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. So, I'd use

```
String pat = "\\[[a-zA-Z]\\w*(?:,[a-zA-Z]\\w*)*]";
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/EIddpT). Use with `String#matches`, or you will have to add `^` (or `\\A`) at the beginning and `$` (or `\\z`) at the end.

```
String pat = "\\[[a-zA-Z]\\w*(?:,[a-zA-Z]\\w*)*]";
System.out.println("[c1,T4,yu5]".matches(pat)); // TRUE
```

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\\[` - a literal `[`
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an English letter (same as `\\p{Alpha}`)
- `\\w*` - zero or more characters from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` set
- `(?:` - start of the non-capturing group matching...

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[a-zA-Z]\\w*` - see above
- `)*` - ... zero or more times
- `]` - a literal `]` (does not require escaping outside of the character class to be treated literally).

Comment: So this is essentially the same regex as Zbynek's except you replaced `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\\w`?

Comment: If it is, then both work for me. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose in the group which could repeat:

```
\[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:,[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_])*\]
```

This is as it should appear in the final string. Escape specials according to specific language.

Comment: It is better for regex performance to make the second half repeating (reduces backtracking), and there's no need to capture anything, so: `\[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:,[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*\]`